# Undefined behaviour when a clone of std::function is created

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

I try to implement a clone of `std::function`. For simplicity, I want to create a class like `std::function` which handles types `int(*)(int)`.

I am facing an issue with the copy constructor. When the call operator of the object (which is created with the copy constructor) is called, sanitizer detects undefined behaviour. Code has potential memory leak since allocated memory is not freed.
Program crashes when a3(5) is called

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int foo(int x )
{
    return x;
}

int bar(int x )
{
    return x*x;
}

class A
{
public:
    A(int(*f)(int))
     :callable_{+[](void *data, int x)->int{
                auto & obj = *static_cast<typename std::decay<int(*)(int)>::type *>(data);
                return obj(x);
    }}
    {    
        f_ = new std::decay<int(*)(int)>::type(f);
    }

    A(A const & other)
    {
        callable_ = other.callable_;
        f_ = new std::decay<int(*)(int)>::type(std::decay<int(*)(int)>::type(other.f_));
    }

    A & operator = (A const & other)
    {
        callable_ = other.callable_;
        f_ = new std::decay<int(*)(int)>::type(std::decay<int(*)(int)>::type(other.f_));
        std::cout << f_ << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }

    int operator()(int x)
    {
        return callable_(f_,5);
    }

    void * f_;
    int (*callable_)(void *data,int) = {};
};

int main() {
    A a1(foo);
    A a2(bar);
    A a3(a1);
    std::cout << a3(5) << std::endl;
}
```

Any idea?

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7zavPeK83)

Comment: Anything you `new` needs to be `delete`'d, otherwise it leaks. But you are decaying the function pointer and storing it in a `void*`, so you lose all type information that `delete` would need to free the memory correctly. Why are you `decay`'ing the function pointer at all? Just store the input pointer as-is, and then call it. You don't need the `void*` at all in this example

Comment: Not sure if behaviour is undefined.   But your constructors and assignment operators of your class all dynamically allocate an object with a `new` expression.   Your class has no destructor (which means you're not following either the rule of 3 or 5) and there is no corresponding `delete` expression, so is definitely a memory leak.   Some "undefined behaviour" detectors do get confused, in some circumstances, in the presence of memory leaks.

Comment: Program crashes when  a3(5) is called.

Comment: It would be easier to read if you expanded all the std::decays. I think that `std::decay<int(*)(int)>::type` is just `int(*)(int)`. Even better, alias it to something like `intfunc`

Comment: `data` is a pointer to a function, but in the lambda you cast it to a pointer to a pointer to a function, then dereference it. This is probably why it crashes. I found this with the help of a debugger.

Comment: If you are only accepting `int(*)(int)`, why do you need `_f` and `_callable`? Just store the function pointer by value.

Comment: To create a class that holds `int (*)(int)`, just create a class that holds `int (*)(int)`. There's no need for all the complexity here; no lambda, no `new`; just store the function pointer in a pointer to function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of allocating memory for the function object `f`, memory is allocated for the pointer which points to this.

To work properly, change the allocation to:

```
 A(const A &other)
    {
        callable_ = other.callable_;
        f_ = new FunctionFunc(*other.f_);
    }
```